# Implementing WebSocket but Callback not found?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Here's my code, which I got more or less [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaWebSockets) :

```
public static WebSocket<String> testwebsocket() {
    return new WebSocket<String>() {

        //Called when the Websocket Handshake is done
        public void onReady(WebSocket.In<String> in, WebSocket.Out<String> out) {

            //For each event received on the socket
            in.onMessage(new Callback<String>() {
                public void invoke(String event) {

                    //Log events to the console
                    println(event);

                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

When I run that I get an error which says "Compilation error: cannot find symbol", which refers to the Callback. I think I need to include something, but I tried including a bunch of libraries and I'm not sure what I am missing. There is no information on the documentation page about this. I am using Play Framework 2.0.4 Java version. Please help me figure out why the Callback symbol cannot be found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this import:

```
import play.libs.F.Callback;
```

If you want a full example for the websockets, you can take a look under the `samples/java/websocket-sample` folder of your Play copy (or take a look at [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/2.0.4/samples/java/websocket-chat)).